# Shallow include in C

Tags: c, header, include

Say I have a header file a.h which includes stdbool.h and say main.c includes a.h. Now, is there a way to make sure that symbols from stdbool.h are not visible in main.c and are only visible in a.h?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. The preprocessor does only textual substitution.

Comment: @gregspears how would you "undef" `typedef foo bar;` ?

Comment: The TL;DR: No, this won't work. And, why would you care if some stdbool symbols get defined? If you don't actually _use_ them, they're pretty much harmless. My guess for the use case is that you have an API you define in `a.h`. Then, in the lib for the API you include `a.h` in your `.c` files. You could split them into `apublic.h` (which minimally defines the API) and `aprivate.h` which does (e.g.) `#include <apublic.h> #include <stdbool.h> #include ...` Now, users of the lib include `apublic.h` and your lib `.c` include `aprivate.h`

Answer (score 1):

No. Only `.c` files are getting compiled andy, if `stdbool.h` isn't visible from a `.c` file, it might as well not be there at all.

Assuming you have a `a.c` file, what you could do is include `stdbool.h` only from `a.c` and maybe use forward declarations, if you want to have access to the types of `stdbool.h` in `a.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility of a macro definition extends from the `#define` directive in which it is defined, to the `#undef` directive that undefines it.

If you want macros seen in `a.h` but not in your source, just `#undef` all of them at the end of `a.h`.  They will not be visible anymore.

Beware because this affects *only* the macros you `#undef`, and not the types defined in `<stdbool.h>` or the constants introduced by that header file (e.g. defined by `enum` type definitions)

I don't actually see why can you need such a thing, but for sure, you are mistaken somewhere.